# How to upgrade kubectl client version

Tags: macos, kubernetes, homebrew, kubectl

I want to upgrade the kubectl client version to 1.11.3.

I executed `brew install kubernetes-cli` but the version doesnt seem to be updating.

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.7", GitCommit:"0c38c362511b20a098d7cd855f1314dad92c2780", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-08-20T10:09:03Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.4", GitCommit:"bf9a868e8ea3d3a8fa53cbb22f566771b3f8068b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-10-25T19:06:30Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I'm trying to get the logs for a cell by running this command.

```
kubectl logs -l groupname/cell=my-cell --all-containers=true
```

This works in my VM which has client version 1.11.3. But in my mac it gives me an error saying `--all-containers=true` flag is not available for `kubectl logs` command.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Install specific version of `kubectl`

```bash
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/<specific-kubectl-version>/bin/darwin/amd64/kubectl
```

For your case if you want to install version `v1.11.3` then replace **specific-kubectl-version** with `v1.11.3`

Then make this binary executable

```bash
chmod +x ./kubectl
```

Then move this binary to your `PATH`

```bash
sudo mv ./kubectl $(which kubectl)
```

Comment: I already installed higher version. If I need to downgrade , then how i can do this ?

Comment: use specific version to download. curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/`<your-desire-version>`/bin/darwin/amd64/kubectl

Comment: You can also use `curl -LO "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/darwin/amd64/kubectl"` to automatically download the latest version

Comment: If using Linux, change the "darwin" bit of URL to "linux"

Answer (score 29):

So, to upgrade kubectl on mac:

```
brew upgrade kubectl
```

Then you 'll probably need:

```
brew link --overwrite kubernetes-cli
```

Comment: if you have ran "brew upgrade kubectl" and get the msg "kubernetes-cli x.x.x is already installed"

then, use "brew link --overwrite kubernetes-cli" to process

oh, save my life~

Answer (score 25):

If you have installed it with `brew`, you can just run `brew upgrade kubernetes-cli`.

Comment: You may get warnings like "kubernetes-cli x.x.x is already installed, it's just not linked". Just follow the prompts for overwriting the link. The messages / warning are very helpful

Answer (score 8):

Step-1 - download latest or version-specific kubectl binary

Refer : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-macos/#install-kubectl-binary-with-curl-on-macos

```
Downloads$ curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/darwin/amd64/kubectl"

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   154  100   154    0     0    583      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   583
100 50.6M  100 50.6M    0     0  9159k      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:-- 10.8M
```

Step-2 : old version

```
➜  Downloads$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.3", GitCommit:"2d3c76f9091b6bec110a5e63777c332469e0cba2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-19T11:13:54Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
```

Step-3 : old kubectl version location :

```
➜  Downloads$ which kubectl
/usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

Step-4 : move new version to the location :

```
➜  Downloads$ sudo mv kubectl /usr/local/bin/.
Password:
```

Step-5 : assign permission to kubectl binary

```
➜  Downloads$ kubectl version
zsh: permission denied: kubectl
➜  Downloads sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

Step-6 : check new version

```
➜  Downloads$ kubectl version                      
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.1", GitCommit:"632ed300f2c34f6d6d15ca4cef3d3c7073412212", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-08-19T15:45:37Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had installed kubectl using google-cloud-sdk. So in my path kubectl was pointing to this location. That is why the version did not update. Kubectl got updated after I removed that from the path.

Answer (score 3):

To install OR upgrade the version of `kubectl` Server and Client on MacOS X is very easy if you follow the detailed install guide on the Kubernetes install page https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-macos

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

Via Chocolatey:

```
choco upgrade kubernetes-cli
```

Comment: if you would like to install specific version `choco upgrade kubernetes-cli --version=1.19.5`

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what boraas said. The version you are seeing is from another kubectl.exe installation. I had docker for windows installed which already has kubectl.exe (located in Docker\resources\bin) and was of older version. This gets used unless you provide explicitly the path to the new location of your kubectl.exe [you need to set it in PATH].

Comment: This solved my issue. Why was kubectl used from the docker resources folder, when I had specified a path for the new kubectl executable?

Answer (score 1):

My docker desktop used an old version of kubectl. After installing `gcloud components install kubectl` the installer yields a warning of the location of the outdated `kubectl` version:

> WARNING:   There are older versions of Google Cloud Platform tools on
>   your system PATH.   Please remove the following to avoid accidentally
>   invoking these old tools:
>
> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/kubectl

I have removed the folder and kubectl run fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thought this helps anybody in the same boat with aws kubectl.

I landed here after I faced problem while downloading kubectl from aws.  kubectl installation was failing because I had kubectl in my machine.

After I removed,  was able to install kubectl 1.15.11 from aws.

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root      admin      55 Jan 11 17:49 kubectl.docker -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/kubectl
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root      admin      55 Jan 11 17:49 kubectl -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/kubectl
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **Windows** and was stuck trying to update my 1.25 kubectl -> 1.27 (latest).
I tried so many times to delete kubectl.exe file and double checking the path to my .exe was added to Path in system Env variables.

The kubectl.exe file that the machine recognized was actually in my **Docker** folder (Program Files-> Docker-> Docker-> resources-> bin).

If this is the same for you on PowerShell:

1. Find where the file is:

```
where.exe kubectl
```

2. Rename old kubectl version (to be safe)

```
Rename-Item "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\kubectl.exe" -NewName "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\kubectl-old.exe"
```

3. Download new aws kubectl.exe in the same directory:

```
curl.exe -O https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/amazon-eks/1.27.1/2023-04-19/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe
```

3. Check version

```
kubectl version --short --client
```

I really hope this works for those who were stuck like me. Good luck!