# 'kubectl get hpa' does not show external metrics displays "<unknown type>"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine

We have our cluster setup in GKE and scaling our pods with 'external metrics' from stack-drive. The scaling works fine, but when I try to see the status with command

$ kubectl get hpa

It shows **'unknown type'** in **TARGET** instead of the actual value as below.

```
NAME                      REFERENCE                            TARGETS          MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
accounts-service          Deployment/accounts-service          <unknown type>        1         200       1          15d
```

My current kubectl version shows as

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.6", GitCommit:"6260bb08c46c31eea6cb538b34a9ceb3e406689c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-12-21T06:34:11Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11+", GitVersion:"v1.11.5-gke.4", GitCommit:"0c81dc1e8c26fa2c47e50072dc7f98923cb2109c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-12-07T00:22:06Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Has anyone faced similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually upgrading the kubectl client in my machine solved this issue.

I followed the steps per the accepted answer and it showed the 'External Metric' as expected.
[How to upgrade kubectl client version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53701151/how-to-upgrade-kubectl-client-version)

Posting it just in case someone else face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to add the following flag to kube-controller of all masters.

> horizontalPodAutoscalerUseRestClients: true

Comment: We are using GKE and kube-controller is abstracted. GKE version 1.9+ has this field enabled. Also, the scaling part is working... when I do a kubectl describe hpa => it says the 'ScalingActive   True    ValidMetricFound  the HPA was able to successfully calculate a replica count from external metric custom.googleapis.com|app_queue_length'   .i.e.. server side its fine. Some thing is missing in kubectl-cli I guess.

Comment: Upgrading the kubectl client in my machine solved this issue. Thanks for sharing ur experience!